# Laravel/Php - Nested Model calling using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Assume the following, I have a:

##### Course Model:

- `belongsToMany` User Model
- `belongsToMany` Exam Model

  - `HasMany` Question Model

    - `HasMany` Answers Model

##### Course Exam Results Table

- `id`
- `user_id`
- `course_id`
- `exam_id`
- `question_id`
- `answer_id`

Is there a better way to get the results without having to directly query the table?

I am currently doing the following:

```php
public function displayResult($user, $course, $exam) {
    $course_exam_results = \App\CourseExamResult::where([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'course_id' => $course->id,
        'exam_id' => $exam->id
    ])
    ->get();

   dd($course_exam_results);
}
```

Would love to do something better like `auth()->user()->course(??)->exam(??)->results`. I thought about using laravel [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) but I don't think I can make it work in this case as it only accepts 2 Models while I might have to call 3-5 models at a time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have not mentioned the `Course` model at all here. Also if answer belongs to a single question and question to a single exam (and exam to a single course?) then `question_id, exam_id, course_id` can be functionally deterimined by `answer_id` which kind of tells me you need to rethink how you've modelled your course exam results models

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple `where`s in Laravel Eloquent, you must do like example below:

- You must give to `where()` an array.
- Every search has two arguments so it is an array in an array.

```php
$course_exam_results = \App\CourseExamResult::where([
    ['user_id', auth()->user()->id],
    ['course_id', $course->id],
    ['exam_id', $exam->id]
])
->firstOrFail();
```